# linq group by two columns and get only rows with same group by values

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I want to retrieve data by group two columns ( `Parent_Id` and `Name` ) using LINQ and get the result only the rows with the same group by values.

```
Child
---------
Id        Parent_Id      Name
1         1              c1
2         1              c2
3         2              c1 <-----
4         2              c1 <-----
5         3              c2
6         3              c3
7         4              c4 <-----
```

As you can see, for `Parent_Id` **1** and **2**, `Name` are different.  So, I don't what those rows.
The result I want is like

```
Parent_Id   Name
2           c1 
4           c4
```

What I have tried is

```
from c in Child
group c by new
    {
        c.Parent_Id,
        c.Name
    } into gcs
    select new Child_Model()
    {
        Parent_Id = gcs.Key.Parent_Id,
        Name= gcs.Key.Name
    };
```

But it return all rows.

Comment: So you want those elements where the combination of `Name` and `Parent_Id` occurs at least twice? Or do you want only those where that combination has the most hits?

Comment: @lidqy, if `Name` and `Parent_Id` are same after group , I will grab this row.

Comment: And you want ALL that have 2 or more occurrences of same p-id+name? Or just one - with the most? I know in your example there is just one, but in real life data will likely change...

Comment: @lidqy, I already updated my question.

Comment: *for Parent_Id 1 and 2, Name are different* -- I guess you mean Parent_Id 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduced to final edit as per Gert Arnold's request:

```
var result = from r in (from c in children
             where !children.Any(cc => cc.Id != c.Id &&
                cc.Parent_Id == c.Parent_Id &&
                cc.Name != c.Name)
             select new  {
                Parent_Id = c.Parent_Id,
                Name = c.Name
             }).Distinct().ToList()
             select new Child_Model
             {
                Parent_Id = r.Parent_Id,
                Name = r.Name
             };
```

Comment: sorry,  I've edited my question, can we remove `c.Count() >1` ? and also can you show me with simple LINQ query, not lambda expression.

Comment: @StevenSann, Oh OK, that makes a difference. I am going to edit my reply.

Answer (score 2):

As you describe it you should group by `Parent_id` only and get the groups that have distinct `Name`s:

```
var result = children
    .GroupBy(c => c.Parent_Id)
    .Where(g => g.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Parent_Id = g.Key,
        Name = g.Select(c => c.Name).First()
    });
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than one using `Distinct` on the result set, as with this you have the option to include the `Id` in the projection, if that is desirable for whatever reason.

Comment: @JohnH, I thought I showed you how to include that. And this still uses Distinct().

Comment: I don't think JohnH is saying that `Distinct` should be avoided. Just that it's used in an earlier stage. The main point here is that the grouping shouldn't include `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to filter result (`groupName.Count() > 1`):

```cs
from c in childs 
group c by new { c.Parent_Id, c.Name } into gcs 
where gcs.Count() > 1 
select new { gcs.Key.Parent_Id, gcs.Key.Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myModel = Child.GroupBy( c => $"{c.Parent_Id}|{c.Name}",
          (k, list) => new Child_Model{
              Parent_Id = list.First().Parent_Id,
              Name = list.First().Parent_Id,
              Count = list.Count()})
          .Max (cm => cm.Count);
```